# Android special permissions from individual manufacturers (especially Huawei)

Tags: android, permissions, huawei-mobile-services

There are some phone manufacturers that require special permissions in order to to routine stuff you would do without any permissions on ordinary phones.

If you don't include those specific permissions in your Manifest, your app crashes.

So, the workflow is something like this:

- Write your ordinary code
- Publish your app
- Notice lots of java.lang.SecurityException alerts in Developer Console
- Somehow find the missing permissions and put them in the Manifest.

For instance:

I have a line of code which requires:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

The code works well on most devices, but on Huawei devices it also needs:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

I have found about the above permission from stackoverflow, after observing some crashes inside the developer console, not from an official source.

As expected, this workflow is time consuming.

Are there any lists of such manufacturer specific permissions? If so, it would be ideal if we could gather them all together.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please elaborate with an example workflow.

Comment: Of course, I have updated the question.